# Unable to run distributed shell on YARN

Tags: hadoop, distributed, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run distributed shell example on YARN cluster.

```
@Test
public void realClusterTest() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");
String[] args = {
"--jar",
APPMASTER_JAR,
"--num_containers",
"1",
"--shell_command",
"ls",
"--master_memory",
"512",
"--container_memory",
"128"
};
LOG.info("Initializing DS Client");
Client client = new Client(new Configuration());
boolean initSuccess = client.init(args);
Assert.assertTrue(initSuccess);
LOG.info("Running DS Client");
boolean result = client.run();
LOG.info("Client run completed. Result=" + result);
Assert.assertTrue(result);
}
```

But it fails with:

```
2013-09-17 11:45:28,338 INFO [main] distributedshell.Client (Client.java:monitorApplication(600)) - Got application report from ASM for, appId=11, clientToAMToken=null, appDiagnostics=Application application_1379338026167_0011 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1379338026167_0011_000002 exited with exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:458)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
................

.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application., appMasterHost=N/A, appQueue=default, appMasterRpcPort=0, appStartTime=1379407525237, yarnAppState=FAILED, distributedFinalState=FAILED, appTrackingUrl=ip-10-232-149-222.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/proxy/application_1379338026167_0011/, appUser=hdfs
```

Here is what I see in server logs:

```
2013-09-17 08:45:26,870 WARN nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(213)) - Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1379338026167_0011_02_000001 and exit code: 1
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:458)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:258)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:74)
```

The question is how can I get more details to identify what is going wrong.

PS: we are using HDP 2.0.5

Comment: check the config for your YARN logs and the hdfs perms.  also check the DN logs.  this smells like a perms issue, it cant launch the job because it cant log to the configured hdfs directory.